# Requirements tracking tool (free alternative to IBM Rational Doors)

Tags: windows, gratis, requirements-management

So, I am starting a fairly complex private project, and would like to do real, professional, requirements gathering & tracing, just as we do at work.

I am looking for something gratis for Windows which covers as much of the functionality of IBM Rational Doors as possible.

- unique Id for each requirement
- linking of requirements, also between documents
- sort, search, filter (colo(u)r)
- insert images
- scripting language not required, but I won't complain about it, or any other bells & whistles ;-)

Since I can Google too, I am hoping that you will only answer with something which you have actually used.

---

[Update] I found http://rmtoo.florath.net and  https://github.com/jacebrowning/doorstop both of which are command line based and work on plain text files. They do have some good features and may be of value to you, but I will continue to search for something GUI based.

---

[Update for bounty] I am offering a minimal 50 point bounty, just to get attention, but will award more for a good answer.

Please be aware of this question and don't post anything mentioned their, either as comment or answer, nor anything already mentioned here, unless you can expand upon it greatly. If I don't get an answer, I might consider coding one myself, either from scratch, or as a GUI for one of those two command line only tools.

Comment: Somewhat related is https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/30796/damn-small-requirements-management-tool

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I hope that is not too late for an answer. We develop ReqView (reqview.com) software and system requirements management tool. I believe that the FREE plan suits most of your needs.

With the FREE plan, you can open any ReqView project as read-only, browse requirements, traceability links, sort, filter and print requirement views. The FREE plan limits size of edited project to a single document (e.g. SRS) with up to 150 objects and a single custom attribute (e.g. requirement status). Our goal was to set up the FREE limits to suits most of personal or university projects.

Let me answer your specific questions:

- unique Id for each requirement: ReqView generates requirement ID as a unique integer with document ID prefix, e.g., "SRS-123"
- linking of requirements, also between documents: with FREE version you can link requirements only within a single document; linking between documents is available in PRO plan
- sort, search, filter (colo(u)r): sort, search and filter are all available in FREE plan without limits; ReqView does not support coloring of requirements, however you can add a custom enumeration attribute representing a color
- insert images: image attachments are available in the FREE plan
- scripting language not required, but I won't complain about it, or any other bells & whistles ;-): you can define template columns using a Handlebars script, however editing template columns is not available in the FREE plan.

With the FREE plan you can also:

- Browse your requirements in a text editor or use a text compare tool because of open file format based on JSON
- Store your requirements project under a version control system together with source code
- Compare the current requirements project with a baseline project file in the tool

I hope you will find it useful. Your feedback is very welcome.

Comment: Lolx! I already discovered ReqView, posted it and had it accepted as answer fot [thsi related question](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/30796/damn-small-requirements-management-tool). Yup! looks  great and teh prices for the small team & enterprises are great - especially when compared with Doors. Keep up the good work !

Comment: On reflection, I would prefer a single user plan for the lone developer. Eur 300 is a lot for a "one o"f, but anually it's a bit too much. maybe something like Inprise's license - free until you earn $5k a year? I have spent many kilohours on projects that came to naught, and would ***gladly*** pay Eur 300 if only I earned *some* money ... but I can't afford to pay so much up front if I won't earn from it

Answer (score 1):

I just noticed that one of the command line tools I mentioned above, [DoorStop](https://github.com/jacebrowning/doorstop), has  an [experimental GIU](https://doorstop.readthedocs.io/en/latest/gui/overview/).

While not perfect, it is a good possibility - but I would like to see other answers.

[image]