# Software Planning Tool

Tags: software-development, project-management, planning

I'm currently designing a medium-sized piece of software and I have many features/ideas that I want to be able to write down and store in an organized manner. I am looking for some kind of software to help me collect my thoughts and list all the features of the product and the requirements.

It needs to be something specific to software design: something that allows me to to write down a project statement, its components, features, and how they will all interact.

Requirements:
    - Windows
    - Preferably Free
    - Not UML software

Additionally:
- Trello isn't really what I'm looking for, it's basically a glorified version of sticky notes.
- I'm not looking for any kind of time management/project management software

Comment: Perhaps look at this question here: [Requirements tracking tool (free alternative to IBM Rational Doors)](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/49354/3075)

Comment: @knb This is exactly what I was looking for; if you post it as an answer I'll mark it correct. Thanks!

Comment: Have a look at [OpenProject](https://www.openproject.org/collaboration-software-features/), which you can self-host or pay for. But I am not sure if your last statement disqualifies OpenProject. I find the question rather unclear in that regard. Anyway, another thing I've worked with is mind-mapping software. It typically allows you to "zoom" in and out, structure stuff topically, attach extra information, but it's not necessarily good for collaborative work (many editors).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you take a look at [Miro](https://miro.com/)?
It's a whiteboard with a variety of template to choose from: just to add sticky notes, make a simple or complex interaction between class or entity or interaction between UI and code behind it, or design your UI...

**plus**: it's collaborative.

**minus**: for free you have just 3 boards.

Comment: This is almost exactly what I was looking for! I'll mark it as correct.

Answer (score 4):

You need to be more specific on the requirements. From what you wrote I could say use notepad. But that's probably not what you had in mind. Maybe something like Trello? Or OneNote if you add handwritten stuff/drawings? (of course you can also include images in trello and use paint or something). Maybe evernote? Or just something like markdown? Maybe some mindmapping software? Of course there's also stuff like MS Project.

Comment: Alright, I edited my question. Could you take another look?

Answer (score 3):

You could take a look at the [iMapping Tool. It is a visual knowledge mapping tool that lets you organize text notes and pictures visually](https://www.imapping.info/) on what could be described as an infinite pinboard (a bit like prezi, or as some users describe it "like Google Maps for Ideas". Items can be nested and interlinked so you can add structure as your collection grows.

Some of our users actually use iMapping to create feature maps and implementation plans of software projects. However it is not a specific software design tool. Instead is is a very flexible knowledge mapping tool, in which you would need to create your own structures for visually managing whatever you want.

The website is in German, while the tool itself is English. Just check out the video - you will get an impression.

Disclaimer: I work for the start-up company that created the iMapping tool and we are currently developing an entirely new, web-based version of it. We sell it commercially. Howeever, there is also an eternally free version availabe.

Comment: Looks pretty good but wish the website was in English. I'll give it a try anyway!

Comment: There is a new browser-based version of it. In english. https://infinitymaps.io/ (Currently in open Beta)